# Insertar Select desde el formulario SQL

Tags: javascript, html5, ajax, mysqli, phpmyadmin

estoy intentando inserta varios valores desde un select option desde un formulario, bueno la idea seria algo si como que cada categoría tiene un color y al seleccionar categórica en el formulario se seleccionara también el color para ser insertado en la base de datos. hay que decir que la tabla de la base d dato de categoría tiene tres campos id_categoría, name, color. hay una segunda tabla donde va insertado el post con descripción, img, + categoría y color para la vista final.
consigo guardar todo menos el color que depende del la id que pasa por el value la sorpresa mía que si pasa una valor por el value inserta en la tabla de db el valor de la id y no el nombre de la categoría y al la hora de guardar el procesos no inserta el color solo el numero de la id. no se si planteo bien la pregunta, hay otra cosa que hay que tener en cuenta tengo poca experiencia en programación.

```js
$q = intval($_GET['q']);

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'dblzmtest');
if (!$con) {
  die('No pudo conectar: '.mysqli_error($con));
}

mysqli_select_db($con, "result");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM categoria WHERE id_categoria = '".$q.
"'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

  echo "<div>".$row['color'].
  "</div>";
}

mysqli_close($con);
```

```html
<?php

include 'conexion.php';



$sql_leer = 'SELECT id_categoria, name, color FROM categoria';
 
$gsent = $pdo->prepare($sql_leer);
$gsent->execute();

$resultado = $gsent->fetchall();

?>

  <script>
    function showUser(str) {
      if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("resltcolor").innerHTML = "";
        return;
      }
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          document.getElementById("resltcolor").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
      }
      xmlhttp.open("GET", "getuser.php?q=" + str, true);
      xmlhttp.send();
    }
  </script>


  <div class="col-md-3">
    <form id="myForm" action="saved_proccess.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <h4 class="text-muted">Categoria:</h4>
      <div class="form-group">
        <select onchange="showUser(this.value)" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="categoria">
          <option value="0">Select Categoria</option>
          <?php foreach($resultado as $dato):?>
          <option value="<?php echo $dato['id_categoria'];?>">
            <?php echo $dato['name'];?>
          </option>
          <?php endforeach ?>
        </select>
      </div>
    </form>
    <div id="resltcolor"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Si es posible utiliza el punto y aparte. Me costó sacar de tu pregunta el problema, que parece ser este: *consigo guardar todo menos el color que depende del la id que pasa por el value la sorpresa mía que si pasa una valor por el value inserta en la tabla de db el valor de la id y no el nombre de la categoría y al la hora de guardar el procesos no inserta el color solo el numero de la id.* Está un poco a modo de trabalengua y no se entiende bien, ¿podrías explicarlo más claro e indicar cuál es la consulta problemática? En el código que compartes no veo ninguna consulta del tipo `INSERT`

Comment: lo siento por las explicaciones amigo no se plantéalo muy bien la verdad. La idea es desde un <select option> coger todo los valore de la misma id seleccionada de una tabla de la base de dato, para rellenar un formulario. para luego insertar en la base de datos de dicho formulario.
gracias por contestar

Comment: La pregunta se puede [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/236779/edit) y mejorarla dando una explicación clara. Si no se entiende el problema es mucho más difícil poder ayudarte.